# Java classLoader within a jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, classloader

I work with the follwing project:

**Test-Project**

```
/lib/classA.jar
/src/main/java/org/test/classB.java
/src/main/resources/log.txt
```

In **classA.jar**, I work with the `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` to get the path of the "log.txt" file. In the project of *classA.jar*, there is no problem with that.

But when I use the jar in the *Test-Project* I get the follwing path to the "log.txt" file:

/lib/classA.jar!/log.txt

Is there a way to get the classloader from *Test-Project* into to the jarfile?

Answer (score 1):

For accessing to a resource file you should use [Class#getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) for reading this file.

```
InputStream stream = Class.class.getResourceAsStream("/log.txt");
```

Note: a jar file is an archive, which is meant to be unchanged, if that is really a log file you shouldn't store it inside a jar file.